# How I redirected according to PHP?

Tags: php, web

I am trying to redirect according to a state in my BD (which is 0 ), but when it changes to " 1" it continues routing the welcome page.

The code I'm trying to use is below.

```
$hash = $loggedInUser->user_id; //This is the variable that I use to declare my User ID program

$tour1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sqlusuarios_users WHERE id=".$hash ,$conexion);
$tour2 = mysql_fetch_array($tour1);

if($tour2['tour'] == "0") { 
    header("Location: bienvenido.php");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should put an `exit()` after redirect. `header()` function only adds additional line in the http response header. It does not stop further script execution.

Also, you should probably use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, instead of `mysql_fetch_array`:

```
$tour1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sqlusuarios_users WHERE id=".$hash ,$conexion);
$tour2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($tour1);

if($tour2['tour'] == "0") {
  header("Location: bienvenido.php");
  exit;
}
```

Also, this might not work if you already have outputed any data to the user and http headers are already sent. This needs to go **before** any actual output, unless you have output buffering enabled.

Comment: but I try this Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in home/u911261314/public_html/abogadro/0.4/account/dashboard.php on line13

Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/u911261314/public_html/abogadro/0.4/account/dashboard.php on line 14  
when the value is 1

Comment: Did you do `$conexion = mysql_connect(...)`?

Comment: <?php
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "USERXXX", "XXX") or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db("XXX", $conexion);
?>  You think this wrong in that?

Comment: Modify if($tour2['tour'] == "0") by if($tour2['tour'] == 0)  and redirects , but when I change the value in one continuous redirecting MySQL... Before, with "0" not even redirected , poor mine.

Comment: The error implies you do not have a proper mysql connection open before trying to use `mysql_query`. You need to work on fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues could be that because warnings are being reported or because some content is being echo'ed out earlier on in the same file it is already sending some form of response.

If this is the case PHP should throw a warning to say you cant modify headers, headers already sent. Which is pretty self explanatory